# What is the word for the numerical portion of a numeric value with units?

Tags: definition

When I see 3 Miles the word "miles" represents the units.  What is the word which 3 represents?  I want to say "scalar value" but I know that's not correct.  Or if it is correct is 4 also the scalar value in the phrase "4 square miles"?  Is the word I'm looking for simply "value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure myself, but I did a little digging and found this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_number

Comment: Great little factoid, thanks.

Comment: My interpretation of this reading of the wiki is that a "concrete number" is a number associated with the things being counted.  The "concrete number" + "unit of measure" is a "denominate number".  So the answer to this question would be "Concrete Number", correct?

Comment: @CoreyAlix Apparently.  Of course, it's really just a naming convention.  This is the first I've heard of something like that and I've been doing math a long time.  We usually just call it a number!